# Is $SU(3)$ generated by the exponentials of the Gell-Mann matrices?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

It is well known that the lie algebra of $SU(3)$ is spanned by the (half) Gell-Mann matrices $T_i=\lambda_i/2$, and that these generate $SU(3)$ via the map $\theta_iT_i \rightarrow e^{\theta_iT_i}$.

However, the above map involves taking a linear combination of the generators and then taking the exponential. Do we generate $SU(3)$ if we take the exponential of this basis first? In other words, is it true that if we take the set $\{{e^{T_i}}\}, i=1,...8$, that these matrices generate $SU(3)$?

Comment: Off the top of my head, by taking $(e^{T_i})^n$ for all $n$, I think you get a dense set of $e^{\theta_i T_i}$ (because it's an irrational rotation).  So the closure contains all $e^{\theta_i T_i}$.  Now if you want $e^{\theta_i T_i + \theta_j T_j}$, the Lie product formula says it is the limit of $(e^{(\theta_i/n) T_i} e^{(\theta_j/n T_j})^n$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The group $SU(3)$ is uncountable, hence, cannot be generated by a finite subset. What's true is that Gell-Mann matrices generate a dense subgroup in $SU(3)$. I suggest you clarify the meaning of the word "generate" that you are using.

Comment: If you just wanted an 8-angle parametrization of the group, suspending its connection to the algebra (which you may then retrieve around the identity, messily) instead, the canonical reference is, of course, [J. B. Bronzan
Phys. Rev. D 38, 1994  (1988)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.38.1994).

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237988/good-reference-on-the-parametrization-of-su3-and-sun).

Answer (score 0):

For SU$(3)$, the following set $F_m$ and its algebraic relations differ from that of the eight Gell Mann generators $g_m$.

The $F_m$ have no simple relation to the $g_m$. For example, in the usual representation, $7$ of the $8$ generators $g_m$ have a diagonal element that is zero;

Is the set of the eight finite SU(3) elements $F_m=e^{\pi \cdot i \cdot g_m / 2}$ $-$ defined by the eight SU(3) generators $g_m$.

Here are the Gell-Man matrices $g_n$:

$g_1=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_2=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & -i & 0\\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_3=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_4=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_5=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & -i\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_6=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_7=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $g_8=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/\sqrt{3} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2/\sqrt{3} \end{array} \right )$,

And these are the first matrices $F_n$:

$F_1=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & i & 0\\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right )$, $F_2=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right )$, $F_3=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} i & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right )$, $F_4=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & i\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $F_5=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $F_6=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{array} \right )$, $F_7=\left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{array} \right )$, Now $ F_8$ is less simple.

Comment: So do these $F_m$ generate $SU(3)$? Also, why is $F_8$ less simple? Surely, since it's diagonal, the exponential is simple to compute?